# Merge rows that are identical except for the last column in SQL, squashing the unique values in the result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, merge, duplicates, distinct

Imagine I own a pet store and have Customers and Pets tables.

If I did a query like

```
SELECT
CUSTOMER.ID,
CUSTOMER.NAME,
CUSTOMER.EMAIL,
PET.NAME
FROM CUSTOMERS
INNER JOIN PETS ON PET.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
```

I should be getting results like

```
[1, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@jd.com', 'Bailey']
```

But if I had customers with multiple pets, that means I'd be getting multiple rows:

```
[1, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@jd.com', 'Bailey'],
[1, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@jd.com', 'Luna']
```

Is there a way for me to somehow condense these rows yet retain the unique values? How would I be able to get a result like

```
[1, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@jd.com', ['Bailey', 'Luna']]
```

?

I tried to SELECT DISTINCT Customer IDs, but I think that only works if that's the only field you're selecting? When I add in the rest of of the fields to select, I still get duplicate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string_agg function to get your desired result -

```
SELECT c.ID, c.NAME, c.EMAIL,
       STRING_AGG(p.NAME, ',')
  FROM CUSTOMERS c
 INNER JOIN PETS p ON p.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID
 GROUP BY c.ID, c.NAME, c.EMAIL;
```

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. I'm using Oracle so what worked for me was `LISTAGG`.

Comment: Most probably, with ROR you use postgres, That why I gave you postgres specific solution. In Oracle you have to use LISTAGG.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets
end
```

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

```
Customer.group(:id)
        .joins(:pets)
        .pluck(
          :id,
          :name,
          "JSON_ARRAYAGG(pets.name)"
        )
```

I haven't used the Oracle adapter for ActiveRecord so YMMV.